# Break Repeated Key XOR

Tags: python, python-2.7, cryptography, hex, xor

I'm working on the matasano crypto challenges [**here**](http://cryptopals.com/sets/1/)

But I'm having a hard time with challenge 6, which does a nice job of outlining the steps needed. I have to try finding the key size, break the cipher text into key size length blocks, transpose the blocks to get block corresponding to each byte of the key size and then solve the transposed blocks as if they were a single character XOR cipher. Conceptually, it all makes sense. But being pretty new to python, my program isn't working as desired. I've gone through and it looks like the hamming distance function below works as its supposed to, and breaking up the hex encoded text works as well. But when it comes time to call `get_max_single_char_xor`, I get a bunch of unreadable text back. Maybe a second pair of eyes can help me figure out what I'm doing wrong or why it's failing to give me readable output.

check out the code below:

```
def calc_hamming_dist(str1, str2):
  diff = 0
  val = int(str1, 16) ^ int(str2, 16)
  while(val != 0):
    diff += 1
    val &= val-1
  return diff

def break_repeating_key_XOR(hex_text):
  keysize = 2
  key_hamming_val = []
  hex_len = len(hex_text)
  print 'hex_len: ' + str(hex_len)

  for b in xrange(2, 40):
    hamming_vals = 0
    pos = 0
    counter = 0
    while(pos + 2*keysize <= hex_len):
        key1 = hex_text[pos:pos+keysize]
        pos += keysize
        key2 = hex_text[pos:pos+keysize]
        pos += keysize
        hamming_vals += calc_hamming_dist(key1, key2)
        counter += 1
    hamming_vals = float(hamming_vals/float(counter))
    key_hamming_val.append((float(hamming_vals/float(keysize)), keysize))
    keysize += 1

  print 'hamming_val length: ' + str(len(key_hamming_val))
  key_hamming_val.sort()
  for a in xrange(2, 38):
    blocks1 = []
    blocks2 = []
    count = 0
    key = ''

    min_hamming, keysize_guess = key_hamming_val[a]
    #for x in range(keysize_guess):
        #blocks2.append('')
    while count <= hex_len:
        blocks1.append(hex_text[count:count+keysize_guess])
        count += keysize_guess
    print str(min_hamming) + ', ' + str(keysize_guess)
    zzz = 0
    for x in blocks1:
        zzz += len(x)
    #print blocks1

    for x in range(keysize_guess):
        count = 0
        in_str = ''
        while count < len(blocks1):
            try:
                in_str += (blocks1[count])[x]
            except IndexError:
                break
            count += 1
        #print in_str
        blocks2.insert(x, in_str)
    zzz = 0
    for x in blocks2:
        zzz += len(x)
    #print blocks2

    for y in blocks2:
        if (len(y) % 2) != 0:
            y = '0' + y
        (score, words, key_guess) = get_max_single_char_xor(y)
        #print ' ' + str(key_guess)
        key += chr(key_guess)

    print key + ' (' + str(len(key)) + ')'
```

A few notes: hex_text being passed in is a string of hex values that have been encoded. Here are some of the functions being called in another module:

```
def score_plaintext(s, val):
  letters = filter(lambda val: 'a'<=val<='z' or 'A'<=val<='Z', s)
  #letters = filter(lambda  val: ' '<=val<='~', s)
  return float(len(letters)) / len(s)

def get_max_single_char_xor(val):
  res = []
  for i in range(256):
    chrs = [chr(ord(s) ^ i) for s in val.decode('hex')]
    res.append([score_plaintext(chrs, val), ''.join(chrs), i])

ret = sorted(res, key=lambda res: res[0], reverse=True)
  for i in ret:
    (score, words, key) = i
    if all(c in string.printable for c in words):
        return i
  return max(res, key=lambda s: s[0])
```

Based on some of the other challenges, the two functions above should be working fine. But I can't be sure.

Anyone see any problems with this code?

Comment: Your question is a little meaty. Can you reduce that to a smaller example, like "given these parameters, I expected this but got this instead"?

Comment: @KirkStrauser: It's hard to narrow it down, but basically I started with the file given in the website, converted it to hex (it's encoded in base64) and continued with that. I know the key is supposed to be 29 characters, but when the results print out, I don't get a low hamming/edit distance for that.

Comment: I did this in C# a couple months ago.  The 29 character key is right, but for me it was the one with the lowest normalized hamming distance.  Remember that to normalize the hamming distance, you need to divide the total hamming distance by the key size.  Once you have that key size, finding the right value to XOR is pretty easy -- for each position in the key, there is probably only one value that, XORed against its positions in the cipher text, will yield good ASCII values at every position.

Comment: Oh, wait, now I noticed that you are dividing by the key size.  Not sure why it isn't working for you.  But yeah, once you have that 29 byte key size, breaking the XOR is like in one of the earlier exercises.  Just imagine if you were doing it by hand, you would take the 1st character of the cipher text and the 30th and the 59th, and each 29th to the end.  All of those are XORs of the same key value.  There is only one key value that will make all of those XORs turn back into readable ASCII letters.  That value will be your key value for that byte position.  Then repeat for the other 28 bytes

Comment: I realize this is 7 months late, I'm not actually up to that problem yet, but I am also trying to do the problems in python ( to better understand python, I'm more of a C++ and Java guy, but want to learn it. ) and happened to see your question in some of my search results.   

Anyway. It looks like you should be using your commented out filter line in score_plaintext, otherwise you're not scoring lines with spaces or punctuation as highly as you should.   ( you probably already figured this out a long time ago. )